# NSTextField Changing Focus Order With Tab Key

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a macOS SwiftUI app that displays a lot of text fields in a grid. Originally I was using SwiftUI TextField's, but they have the problem that you cannot set the focus order of them (the order they receive focus when you press the tab button). I need to change the focus order from horizontal row-by-row, to vertical column-by-column. There does not appear to be an easy way to do this in SwiftUI.

I found a solution for iOS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559849/does-swiftui-have-something-like-cocoas-nextkeyview-so-that-i-can-specify-the), that I tried to modify for mac. The problem is that the delegate functions are not getting called. My current code is below. How do I fix this?

Edit: I've updated my code in light of some of the comments, but the problem still remains the same: no delegate methods are being called.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OrderedTextField: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var selectedField: Int
    
    var tag: Int
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<OrderedTextField>) -> NSTextField {
        let textField = NSTextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.tag = tag
        textField.placeholderString = ""
        return textField
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<OrderedTextField>) {
        context.coordinator.newSelection = { newSelection in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.selectedField = newSelection
            }
        }
        
        if nsView.tag == self.selectedField {
            nsView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

extension OrderedTextField {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        var newSelection: (Int) -> () = { _ in }
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            print("Initializing!")
            _text = text
        }
    
        func textShouldBeginEditing(_ textObject: NSText) -> Bool {
            print("Should begin editing!")
            return true
        }
        
        func textDidBeginEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
            print("Began editing")
        }
    
        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            print("textDidChange")
        }
        
        func textShouldEndEditing(_ textObject: NSText) -> Bool {
            print("should end editing")
            return true
        }
        
        func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
            print("did end editing")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I have tried using @FocusState to implement this using pure SwiftUI code. It works for a small number of TextField's but because my app is somewhat complicated the compiler cannot handle it yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191763/2303865

Comment: Something like that may work. I would have to rearchitect what I'm doing to try it. It doesn't address the problem of why the delegate functions aren't being called. Which is probably due to some misunderstanding of how things are supposed to work.

Comment: See [becomeFirstResponder()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1526750-becomefirstresponder/): "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder(_:) method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly."

Comment: `NSTextFieldDelegate` and `UITextFieldDelegate` don't have the same methods.

Comment: I've changed it locally to only use NSTextFieldDelegate methods and they are still never called.

Comment: What is 'makeNSView' for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select next NSTextField with Tab key in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000867/select-next-nstextfield-with-tab-key-in-swift)

Comment: That is using Interface Builder and I'm not sure how to covert that solution to SwiftUI. It probably would work but I'd prefer to stick with SwiftUI if it's possible.